# why does adaptive subdivision misses its target dicing scale?

Tags: displacement

I've been using it for years, but I'm still confused. Here I have a 1 million poly scene, with a render dicing scale at 12 pixels.
So it should barely subdivide like 2-3 times, but rendering a crop image with a wireframe shader override, I see that some pieces are subdivided way more than what they should with 12px dicing scale, they seem to even have several subdiv per pixel...
[image: too much subdiv for 12px dicing]
So it took 6 minutes to compute the subdivs, 40 Gb of Ram, and filled my 24 Gb of Vram.
The strangest is that some objects are way more subdiv than others, althought subdivs shouls be in kinda pixel space, not object space.

Thanks for any hint on understanding how to keep these subdivs under control.

Comment: The strange thing is also than in viewport it does work nicely, subdivs are quite right as the meshes gets closer to the camera, but it works like this only if the viewport subdivs are set to Zero in the modifier, as otherwise it just brute force carpets adds whatever viewport subdiv you input instead of zero.

One reason it takes this much ram (40Gb) on this simple scene is probably that my objects are multi-users, so the adaptive subdiv turns them into single users, but most of the geometry is also just collection instances, and these are said to remain as instances in the documentation.

Comment: I just tried a dicing rate of 512px, that should prevent any subdiv, and I get the exact same result, 40Gb or geometry divided smaller than a pixel.

Comment: Doing more tests, on another scene a high dicing rate value does seem to prevent subdiv, so it might be a bug, but the minimum amount of subdiv is not 0, but 1, so all objects will be subdivided once at the minimum, even if they're super high poly and far away from the camera.
That might be why some objects are overly subdivided, they are already having faces smaller than a pixels, but the adaptive subdiv brute forces a minimum of 1 subdiv, no matter the pixel size of the object's faces.